# Tooltip BarChart with primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, bar-chart

I created a bar chart type chart with primefaces and I want the tooltip to always appear at the top of each bar... but I'm not able to implement it.

I tried this on css:

```
.chart-tooltip{
   width:120px;
   bottom: 100%;
   left:50%
   margin-left:-60px;
}
```

and this in my createBarModel function, but it still doesn't work

```
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.setMode("index");
        tooltip.setIntersect(false);
        options.setTooltip(tooltip);  
         
        stackedBarModel.setOptions(options);
```

How can i do this?

Comment: see https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/charts?id=interactive-chart section "Extender" and https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/ and then make your javascript to configure whatever you want